# How to truly make a navigation bar 100% width

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my personal website and when I originally designed it (http://flic.kr/p/83TsXa) it had two horizontal bars that where supposed to extend 100% of the total width of the website, but when I wrote the code I could not get the page to display properly (please see what I mean - www.gaspyweb.com). What am I doing wrong here? What can I do to get the Navigation and the footer bar to display like in the design that I made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<body>` tag of your page has an 8px margin.  Once you remove that margin your header and footer bars should extend to 100% of the page.  Just to keep it simple add code like this:

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

The easiest way to figure this out is to use a tool like Firebug to check your elements of your page. It will quickly show you where your CSS issue is.

Comment: Note that the 8px margin is assigned by your useragent, not the page itself, so the amount might vary across different web browsers.